# Can't find Takemura on the mission "Down the Street"

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I was playing "Down on the street" and when I got the choice to ride with Takemura I selected to go alone. When I arrived to jig-jig street I instantly got a different objective and didn't get the chance to meet with Wakako. The new objective was to "talk to Takemura" when I arrived there it looked like Takemura was somewhere under the ground. There was a door that looked like it led there but it was locked. Is there any way to get there or restart the mission entirely? I've tried restarting the game and this is the only main quest I currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Takemura is not present at the mission marker, the mission marker indicates a location near a barrier that you need to go to and then "use" to wait for Takemura to arrive.

[image: World map of the mission marker location]

You need to go down to the docks (which is on a very low level, underneath the main city but the sky is still visible) and then lean against a barrier at the mission marker. This will start a conversation with Takemura when he arrives.

[image: Mission start location]